# Should we migrate AUCTeX questions if/when Emacs.SE goes live?

Tags: discussion, migration

Emacs.SE (currently in beta but [is anticipated to graduate](https://emacs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/2264)) has a pretty active [auctex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auctex) tag going on.  As TeX.SE is about the underlying TeXnology (and not really the editor), should we encourage new questions about AUCTeX be asked over on Emacs.SE?

See the Emacs.SE [(auctex)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auctex) tag.

Comment: General StackExchange policy is old questions shouldn't (and can't) be migrated: I assume the focus is new questions.

Comment: @JosephWright I didn't know that, but it's completely reasonable considering it'd be a monumental task.  So yes, I'll edit the question to focus on new questions only.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The general rules on what are 'good' migrations are that the question should be

- well-written
- on-topic on the target site
- not on-topic for the 'source' site

The last point is important in the sense that the original poster has made some form of choice of where to ask: it might be accidental, but it might equally be deliberate if the question is arguably on-topic for more than one place.

The case of Emacs and specifically AUCTeX questions falls at least partly within the 'TeX-related editors' area that we have been happy to have on TeX-sx. However, that's something of a compromise: we know that sometimes the 'TeX element' is more-or-less zero, but with no better place to point to we've preferred to give people the benefit of the doubt. The new site means we at least need to think about the balance.

I'd say that we can't make a blanket 'questions will be migrated' decision, at least at this stage. What we can do is look out for things that make the question more likely to be answered on the new site. Most obvious there would be ones that look likely to have general Emacs answers (*i.e.* the fact that TeX is involved is parenthetic) or where there is an element of Emacs programming involved. Less clear are those tied to AUCTeX where there is a strong 'TeX element': they are likely to be similar to questions asked about other editors where we would allow them. I'd be tempted in such cases to point the OP to the new site and suggest we can migrate if they want. That leaves the OP with some 'ownership' while still trying to achieve the point: get them good answers quickly.

Comment: As I've commented on the question, I'm thinking here of new posts about Emacs/AUCTeX/...: old questions don't get migrated.

Comment: Is it possible to clone the entry in some way? So that it shows up both on Emacs.SX as well as TeX.SX? That way people can continue to access the question in whatever way they feel like.

Comment: @1010011010 That has been brought before and rejected always, AFAIK. I have to admit that I agree with that decision, it would make it complicated. You get different policies on different sites, different moderators, etc.

Comment: @1010011010 See for example http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: @tohecz From what I read, it is not really "always rejected", see for example this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219824/266014

Comment: @T.Verron Still, despite it's an answer from a CM, there's been nothing more for 8 months. Especially, there seems to be no track of Shog9 giving any insight, which is a general sign of "lack of interest" from SE HQ.

Comment: Oh, yes, I just wanted to point out that there is still hope. Given Joseph Wright's link, it's not "always accepted" either, after all. And from what I understand, CM on meta does not necessarily mean dev, and the backlog on feature requests (especially non critical ones) is quite large for the sx network (that's not necessarily a problem either, that allows for more mature ideas to reach the devs).